# What is the URL scheme for the iOS 6.0 maps app?

Tags: ios, mapkit, ios6, ios6-maps

Previously, within an iOS app you could launch the Maps app from within your application by using the Google Maps URL scheme (http:maps.google.whatever.whatever).

Does anyone know what the new URL scheme for the iOS 6.0 Maps app is?  I can't find any new documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use MKMapItem to open the maps application. Take a look at the documentation: [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here's how to use it:

```
MKMapItem *mapItem=[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:yourPlacemark];
[mapItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsMapTypeKey : @(yourMapType), MKLaunchOptionsShowsTrafficKey : @(yourTraffic), MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : yourDirectionMode}];
```

Comment: You can also use OpenUrl with "http://maps.apple.com/maps?" with your own parameters. I have tested this as working on my iOS6 iPhone.

Comment: That will open Google maps only.. :/

Answer (score 2):

While you will get more control by using an `MKMapItem`, the URL scheme is far easier. It hasn't changed much, you just replace google.com with apple.com. [Here's the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html).